# Converting Posix Regex to PCRE in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a cms that on the front-end grabs pages by id, as shown here:

```
$pageid = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $_GET['pid']);
```

This is some old code I am trying to update since POSIX is deprecated, however my efforts to convert (using preg_replace) have been unsuccessful. If anyone could convert that line for me, I would greatly appreciate it.

**Add code from comments**

My first guess was something along the lines of

```
$pageid = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_GET['pid'];
```

Which gave errors, so I further reduced it to

```
$pageid = preg_replace("/^0-9/","",$_GET['pid']
```

Forgive me, my understanding of regex is rather limited.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: @john-conde My first guess was something along the lines of
        $pageid = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_GET['pid'];
Which gave errors, so I further reduced it to 
        $pageid = preg_replace("/^0-9/","",$_GET['pid']
Forgive me, my understanding of regex is rather limited. Thank you.

Comment: What error have you got? Your first attempt seems correct except a missing closing parens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's explain what the posix pattern does.

`[^0-9]`

`[` is the start of a character class and `]` is the end.
When the character class starts with a `^` it means it's inverted (= matches everything but what is listed).
`0-9` is all digits.

So globally `[^0-9]` matches everything which is **NOT** a digit.

The same pattern is also available in PCRE so this will work:

```
$page_id = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['pid']);
```

PCRE has some nice shortcuts to express things.
For example `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d` (d stands for digits)
Also `\D` (using a capital letter) is the inverse and thus equivalent to `[^0-9]`.

Which leads to the following:

```
$page_id = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $_GET['pid']);
```